# Is cross-validation enough to prevent overfitting?

Tags: cross-validation, overfitting

If I have a data, and I run a classification (let's say random forest on this data) with cross validation (let's say 5-folds), could I conclude that there is no over fitting in my method?

Comment: FYI: [How does cross-validation overcome the overfitting problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9053/how-does-cross-validation-overcome-the-overfitting-problem)